# Page refresh increases request size, CPU time and context switches in Django. Why is it happening like this?

Tags: django

This is what I observed after debugging my blog app [while working on this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609982/having-problems-with-django-context-processors).

Link : [Having Problems with Django Context Processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609982/having-problems-with-django-context-processors)

While debugging my blog app, I found out if I refresh the page once, it responds normally. But when I refresh it thrice or maybe more it gives me errors with **large** number of **request size, CPU time and voluntary/involuntary context switches**. Eventually leaving me with a **fail to allocate memory** error about which I am still concerned.

I guess on the server side, processing the request does not stop when I load the page more than once. Hence I get **thousands** of context switches and large total CPU time with errors.

*Basically its like a DDoS attack on very very small scale. My app would definitely crash if its on a large scale.*

Is there any way that I can design my blog app so that it responds to only one request at a time? Or is there any other possible solution to my problem ?

Comment: @catherine I am using it in every page and it is being called in every page of my blog app. its the number of page requests I am concerned about.

Comment: how about you use pjax? it load only the body you want to show not the entire page

Comment: that too is good. But ive only heard of it never used it. I am thinking of keeping it to another (mini)app named `quotes` which would do get quotes for me instead of a context processor. :/

Comment: That's also good. And about the pjax I use it also in my website and it's working good, light like 1KB, it's a simple app :)